# How to insert an external image link to dokuwiki?

Tags: php, image, dokuwiki

I want to insert an image to dokuwiki without uploading the image to the server where the dokuwiki is hosted, like `<img src="http://cdn-domain/xxx.png">` does.

How can I realize it? I have tried `{{http://cdn-domain/xxx.png}}`. However, it will use `fetch.php` to use my server as a proxy which will burden my server. Since my images are stored in an external cloud storage service, I want to direct link to the image like `<img>` tag does.

Answer (score 2):

As I replied to your cross-posts on DokuWiki's forum and GitHub issues:

> It is currently not possible to use external media URLs and have them used directly. But as I wrote in the forum:
>
> > The "burden" to your server is **extremely minimal** as the proxy does not download the image itself, it only **redirects** to the original image (unless you changed the default [fetchsize config option](https://www.dokuwiki.org/config:fetchsize)).

Answer (score 1):

This is one of samples. Important thing is that at the end must be an image extension.

```
{{http://kalsey.com/tools/buttonmaker/button.php?barPosition=50&leftText=Dynamic&leftTextColor=ffffff&rightText=IMG&rightTextPosition=54&.png?}}
```

More details here: https://www.dokuwiki.org/images#dynamic_images

Comment: It will use `/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=url` to fetch the image through my server and fill it, which will consume my server network traffic. I want user's browser can directly request the media with `url`